# How to split up components with Laravel Livewire

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

I am using Livewire for the first time in my Laravel app.  I have a few components (quotes, plans, directory) that are used almost the same for three different types of users (Admins, HR, Advisors).  The views of these components are almost identical but the data returned is different for each type of user.  For example, an HR can only see their plans while an Admin can see all plans.

I am not sure whether I should build separate components for each user (i.e. Quotes for Admins, Quotes for HR, Quotes for Advisors) or try to use one component (i.e. Quotes) and then use a bunch of If Statements within my component's controller.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

You can use single Quotes component with if else statement and separate the common html of this component in separate blade partial file or  native blade component. This will help you reuse your html code which you can modify easily after on.

Note: If you don't have any ajax request inside the livewire component , you actually don't need to use livewire component. native blade component is just fine.